# Train Route from CDG to Calais

Tags: trains, public-transport, france, airport-transfer, cdg

What is the train route from Charles de Gaulle airport to Calais? I see that there is a train station inside the airport. Is there only one station or many? If there are many stations please let me know the station name and the train to board and the route.

I hope the train is the cheapest and best mode to travel from CDG to Calais, if there is any other please suggest.

Comment: You need to clarify "best". Cheapest it might not be but the fastest is the TGV to Lille and then another TGV or even the Eurostar to Calais.

Answer (score 5):

As chx pointed out, you will need to clarify what "best" is. Cheaper? Faster? Most convenient? Most frequent?

I'll concentrate on the train part.

There are two train stations in CDG:

- "**Aéroport Charles de Gaulle 1**" is only served by the "**RER**" (suburban train / express metro). It is located in "Roissypôle", which is about halfway between Terminal 1 and Terminal 2, and close to Terminal 3. You can get to it using the free people mover from T1 or T2, or by foot from T3. The RER B line which serves the station goes through the centre of Paris, serving Gare du Nord. From Gare du Nord you have very frequent trains to Lille, as well as a few trains to Calais.
- "**Aéroport Charles de Gaulle 2 TGV**" is served by both the **RER** B like the other station and by **TGV** (high-speed) trains to many destinations around France. There are no direct trains to Calais that I know of, but there are quite a few trains going to Lille, and you can change there to get to Calais. The station is in the middle of Terminal 2, between halls C, D, E and F.

Note that in Calais there are two stations as well:

- "**Calais Ville**" is the historic train station in the centre of town.
- "**Calais-Frethun**" is the train station of the high-speed line just before entering the Channel Tunnel. It is quite a bit outside Calais proper, though there are trains going from one to the other.

Finally, as many of the options involve changing trains in Lille, there are two relevant stations in Lille as well:

- "**Lille Flandres**" is the historic train station, with both TGV and regional trains
- "**Lille Europe**" is the newer train station on the high-speed line, served only by TGV and some Eurostar services. The two stations are very close to each other, and there's also both the metro and a tram line (underground as well in that part) that link the two. The metro has higher frequencies. But unless it rains or you have lots of luggage, just walk!

So considering just trains, you have (at least) the following options:

- CDG 2-TGV to Lille Europe (TGV) then Lille Europe to Calais-Frethun (mostly TGV, but there's also a "TERGV", regional train using a TGV trainset). This is the fastest option, a bit over 2 hours, most of which is waiting in Lille Europe. Probably the most expensive as well, though that varies greatly.
- CDG 2-TGV to Lille Flandres (TGV) then Lille Flandres to Calais Ville (regional train, quite a bit slower, but probably quite a bit cheaper).
- CDG 1 or CDG 2-TGV to Paris Gare du Nord (RER B) then Paris Gare du Nord to Calais (direct by TGV) or to Lille then Calais (same kind of options as above). This is probably the one that will give you the most choices in terms of schedule, and it may be cheaper, but it's be longer an much less convenient.

There's quite a bit of variation in terms of travel time, frequency, and price range between the different options. Note that prices can vary dramatically from one train to the next even going through the exact same combination, so feel free to examine as many options as you can if you want to get the best price. Note that some fares are either time-sensitive or have quotas (like on planes), so the earlier you book, the more chances you have for a cheap ticket.

Comment: Minor nit - the effective public transport link between the two Lille stations is the Lille Metro. The Lille Europe tram stop is actually a short walk from the station, and the trams aren't nearly as frequent as the metro! That said, unless it's raining, it's normally quicker and easier to just walk...

Comment: @Gagravarr, thanks, updated. It's been a while since I was last in Lille so I had forgotten about the metro between those two stations, remembered the tram because I used to take it regularly (to go further) at one point.

Comment: Thanks for the info.How amny train station are there between CDG 2-TGV to Lille Flandres (TGV). Where can I find that info?

Comment: The authoritative source for information is the national railway company (SNCF) website: www.voyages-sncf.com

Comment: Most trains from CDG 2-TGV go to Lille Europe (over a dozen a day, I'm actually surprised there are that many). There are apparently only two that go to Lille Flandres. But again, the two stations are really close (not even 500 m).

Comment: Can we get train tickets at cd2 station directly to calais ville/calai Frethun or should we just get to Lile Flandres/Lile Europe. Also please let me know the procedure and where to get the train ticket. Thanks for all the info given so far. It was really helpful!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you get your ticket in advance, as you may get a much better deal that a last minute purchase. You can definitely purchase tickets at the last minute at the CDG 2-TGV train station, either at the automated kiosks (though you'll need a Visa or MasterCard with Chip and PIN) or at the counter (though there may be quite a bit of a wait at certain times).

Answer (score 3):

[Rome2Rio says that you can get a Eurolines bus from Paris CDG to Calais.](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris-CDG-Airport-CDG/Calais) The journey lasts approximately 5 hours and is significantly cheaper than the train. Below is a screenshot from Rome2Rio:

[image: Rome2Rio bus from CDG to Calais]

[Eurolines](http://booking.eurolines.fr/site/SelectDestinationSrv#) agrees with this. Buses run to Calais Centre Ville, Calais Ferry, and Calais-Cité-Europe. Below is a sample quote for CDG to Calais Centre:

[image: Eurolines from CDG to Calais]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to decide your price / time balance. You can save money by taking the bus but it's slower than by train.

As mentioned you can take the train directly from CDG Terminal 2. Some require a change, or even change between two different stations, in Lille. Details here [Voyages-SNCF](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/). Generally from around €30.

Eurolines does have one direct bus most days from the airport directly to Calais. You can save even more though by going into Paris and catching a bus from there. You can compare bus options [here on Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-paris-calais/r/u09tvm-u113f5) (full disclosure: I work on this project). Generally from around €10.

Answer (score 1):

The train station is located in Terminal 2 (between 2D and 2F).

Not sure if the train will be the cheapest way to go to Calais. The bus or a shared car might be cheaper (but also take more time).

For instance, with the bus, you can get to Lille from CDG for just 9€ :
http://uk.ouibus.com

Then from Lille to Calais, with the bus, train or shared car, it will be less than 30 €.

For the shared car, try this :
https://www.blablacar.fr/

Hope this helps! :)